# How do I fill [] with sheet information from pandas and xlrd?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlrd

I have this:

```
dic_sheets = {}
for y in xl_files[]
    dic_sheets.update({y:[]})
```

I want to populate the tables in the dictionary (dic_sheets) for each key(y) with the individual sheets inside of the excel document.

I do not know how many sheets are inside of the excel document; I don't have an index number to stop a range (x,y,z) loop.

Another way to put it: I want to dump x-number of excel files into the active directory and have each files sheets populate in a dictionary when I run the `.py` in CMD.

Can anyone help me achieve this goal?

```
xl_files contains "ExcelFile" data "pandas.io.excel.ExcelFile object at 0x0FF6B0D0
```

Edit: `y` represents individual excel files
Edit2: I need only the sheet names (or their unique index numbers) to populate, (i.e. 'sheet1', 'pivot2'). I'm not yet concerned with cells in the sheets.
Edit3: I already have the table ‘xl_files’ generated to contain every excel file in the cwd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!
I had to use a `for` loop and the `return` function as an object, then combine it with another object of the `array.append` function and `return` function with a new array. 
I'll try to word my questions better in the future, as I did not get a bite this round.